# Ensure Replace Text function only looks at a specific Word table VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word table where I apply a routine that replaces paragraph marks with a comma and a space.  However, in doing so there is now some text like '..., There...' and my client wanted to replace the Upper Case to Lower Case as much as possible.

So, I wrote some secondary code that I call from the previous routine as follows:

```
Sub LowerCaseAfterComma()
    With Selection.Find
       .ClearFormatting
       .Text = ", ([A-Z])"
       .Forward = True
       .Wrap = wdFindStop
       .Format = True
       .MatchCase = False
       .MatchWholeWord = False
       .MatchWildcards = True
       .MatchSoundsLike = False
       .MatchAllWordForms = False
       .Execute 
    While .Found
        Selection.Range.Case = wdLowerCase
        Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        .Execute
    Wend
  End With
End Sub
```

Although this identifies the instances of Upper Case characters in the table and replaces them accordingly, the code then looks for all other instances outside the table in the document, which I don't want the code to do.  I have tried using the Range object in Word for the table I want edited but haven't been successful in the syntax needed.

NB. I have problems in ensuring the editing stays within the specific table. There can be a differing number of tables prior to the one I wish to edit so
`ActiveDocument.Tables()` specifying the number of the table doesn't seem to work.
I am sure I doing some basically wrong and the code just needs a little tinkering. However, I am just a novice developer learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  Set Rng = .Range
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = ", ([A-Z])"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      If .InRange(Rng) Then
        .Case = wdLowerCase
      Else
        Exit Do
      End If
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The range statement you included I had already tried however, it was the extra code in the Do While and Loop that solved my problem. To me the Find and Replace function in Word isn't as clear as I would like yet I have learnt a lot researching the topic...and that's what it's all about.

Comment: What you need to understand about the Find and Replace function in Word is that, if something is found, the current Range relocates to the found range. So, storing the designated range in Rng beforehand, then testing whether we're still within it via .InRange(Rng) allows the code to exit when .InRange(Rng) becomes false.